# How to show Git revisions that are either tips of branches or not merges?

Tags: git

I currently use `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` to look at my project's history. However, proficient use of branches causes (quite literally) half the screen to be filled with "Merge branch ..." commits.

I tried adding `--no-merges`, but this also excludes a commit if it is a tip of a branch, which are really important for seeing the current state of my project. Is there a way to exclude merge commits, unless they are the tip of a branch? I also want to include commits from other branches in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Yo should use the following combination (The first one is not mandatory but is recommended)

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges

or

git log --max-parents=1
```

Comment: Doesn't `--first-parent` exclude the other parents of the merge? I want to exclude the merge commit itself, but include both of its parents in the tree. I'll try your second suggestion after the weekend. :)

Comment: I just tried using `--first-parent --no-merges` and it excludes both the merge commits that happen to be branch tips AND the commits from other branches. Those are things that I wanted to include in the output.

Comment: I also tried using `--max-parents=1` and it does include the commits from other branches, but it excludes merge commits that happen to be branch tips. So that's not what I wanted either. :(

Comment: What is it that you trying to do? you want to show all commits that are not merged as u said, `--no-merges` hide those merges log entries.
What is a merge? to make it simple is a log entry with 2 commits. when you "filter" them out you will not see any of them.

Comment: `--max-parents=1` will return the entries which has single parent = no merge entries since merge has at least 2 parents.

Comment: That's right. However, I want to override that whenever the merge entry is the tip of a branch. If an entry has two parents, and is **not** the tip of a branch, then it **should not** appear. If an entry has two parents, and is the tip of a branch, then it **should** appear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `--simplify-by-decoration` is what’s missing:[1]

```
       --simplify-by-decoration
           Commits that are referred by some branch or tag are selected.
```

This one includes true merge commits which are on tags or branches:

```
git log --no-merges --simplify-by-decoration --graph --all --oneline
```

#### Notes

1. From `man git log` on Git 2.40.0